# How to find the exact text string in a column of sheet using excel vba code

Tags: vba, excel

How can I find the exact string matching to particular cell value using Excel VBA. For example if I want to search "userid"(whole string only) in column A. I am able to write some lines of code but the program is not able to find the whole word, even if I type some of the letters in the string  matching the whole word. 
Code is as given below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Username As String, password As String
Dim FindRow1 As Range, FindRow2 As Range
Dim WB As Workbook

Username = "user"
password = "pass"
Set WB = ThisWorkbook

With WB.Sheets("Master_Data")
Set FindRow1 = .Range("A:A").Find(What:=Username, LookIn:=xlValues)
Set FindRow2 = .Range("B:B").Find(What:=password, LookIn:=xlValues)
End With
MsgBox FindRow1
MsgBox FindRow2
```

Here I am getting output in msgbox as userid and password even if I pass the values as username = "user" and password = "pass" which is logically wrong.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the `LookAt` parameter of [`Range.Find()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx):

```
Set FindRow1 = .Range("A:A").Find(What:=username, LookIn:=xlvalues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
Set FindRow2 = .Range("B:B").Find(What:=password, LookIn:=xlvalues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

Comment: LookAt:=xlwhole  works for me and saves a lot of time. Phylogenesis thank for the help!!!!

Comment: @ashishvb Mark the answer as the working solution if it works for you.

Comment: that solution Works for me .